# A pair of integrals involving square roots and inverse trigonometric functions over the unit disk

Tags: integration

I would like to perform the integration ($u \in [0,1]$),
\begin{equation}
\int_{a=-1}^1 \int_{b=-\sqrt{1-a^2}}^{\sqrt{1-a^2}}  u^2 \sqrt{-a^2 u^2-b^2+1} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\left| a\right|
   }{\sqrt{-a^2-b^2+1}}\right) db da .
\end{equation}

I also have a companion problem
\begin{equation}
\int_{a=-1}^1 \int_{b=-\sqrt{1-a^2}}^{\sqrt{1-a^2}} u \sqrt{-a^2-b^2+1} \tan ^{-1}\left(u \left| a\right|  \sqrt{-\frac{1}{a^2
   u^2+b^2-1}}\right) db da .
\end{equation}

Solutions to these two problems would provide a resolution to the question 
"Compute a certain "separability probability" via a constrained 4D integration over $[-1,1]^4$", posed in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193337/compute-a-certain-separability-probability-via-a-constrained-4d-integration-ov

Now, for the component functions of the first integrand, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{a=-1}^1 \int_{b=-\sqrt{1-a^2}}^{\sqrt{1-a^2}}  u^2 \sqrt{-a^2 u^2-b^2+1} db da = \frac{4}{3} u \left(\sqrt{1-u^2} u+\sin ^{-1}(u)\right),
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\int_{a=-1}^1 \int_{b=-\sqrt{1-a^2}}^{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\left| a\right| }{\sqrt{-a^2-b^2+1}}\right) db da=\frac{1}{2} (\pi -2) \pi.
\end{equation}
Can some form of integration-by-parts--or other methodology--be performed? (I realize that more may certainly be needed in addition to the two above results.)

The much-viewed question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167346/integration-by-parts-for-a-double-integral seems relevant here.

Comment: To get rid of at least one integral, first change $a, b$ to polar coordinates $r, \theta$, and change again to $x, y$ with $r = x/\sqrt{1+x^2}, \cos(\theta) = y/x$ with bounds $x \in [0, \infty)$ and $y \in [0, x]$. Switching the integration order to $y \in [0, \infty)$, $x \in [y, \infty)$ then allows you to perform the $x$-integral, and $$\int_0^\infty \! \frac{8 u^2 \sqrt{1 + (1-u^2) \, y^2} \tan^{-1}(y)}{3 (1 + y^2)^2} \, dy$$ remains. Not sure how helpful that actually is though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comment, one can set $y = \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ to obtain $$\frac{8}{3} \, u^2 \int_0^1 \! \sqrt{1 - u^2 z^2} \sin^{-1}(z) \, dz \;,$$ which *Mathematica* evaluates to
$$
\frac{2}{3} \, u \, \bigl(\operatorname{Li}_2(-u) - \operatorname{Li}_2(u) + \pi \sqrt{1 - u^2} \, u - (1 - u^2) \tanh^{-1}(u) - u + \pi \sin^{-1}(u)\bigr) \;,
$$
where $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$ is the dilogarithm.

---

A very similar derivation for your companion problem yields the final integral $$\frac{8}{3} \, u \int_0^1 \! \sqrt{1 - z^2} \sin^{-1}(u z) \, dz$$ which *Mathematica* evaluates to $$-\frac{2}{3u} \, \bigl(u^2 \, \operatorname{Li}_2(-u) - u^2 \, \operatorname{Li}_2(u) - (1 - u^2) \tanh^{-1}(u) + u\bigr) \;.$$

---

For completeness, we can also do the third integral (from the comments) in exactly the same way, yielding $$\frac{8}{\pi} \, u^2 \int_0^1 \! \sqrt{1 - u^2 z^2} \, dz$$ as the final integral, which evaluates to $$\frac{4}{\pi} \, u \, \bigl(\sqrt{1 - u^2} \, u + \sin^{-1}(u)\bigr) \;.$$

---

Bonus round: If $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$ are the three results above, and $$A = \frac{6}{\pi^2} \, (I_2 - I_1) + I_3 \;, \\ B = \frac{12 u^2 \left(u^6+9 u^4-9 u^2-12 \left(u^4+u^2\right) \log (u)-1\right)}{\left(u^2-1\right)^5} \;,$$ then we are also interested in the integral of $AB$ over $u \in [0,1]$. That seems quite impossible, but we are in luck: integrating twice by parts, differentiating each time the factor with dilogarithms, yields a simple integral in $u$ that can be evaluated. The result is $$\frac{256-168 \zeta (3)}{\pi ^2}-38+48 \log (2) \approx 0.747925 \;.$$

Comment: Great! Quick numerical integrations give me agreement with both of your results to eight decimal places. I will incorporate your findings in my related question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193337/compute-a-certain-separability-probability-via-a-constrained-4d-integration-ov

Comment: For simplicity, I omitted certain numerical factors that appear in 
the subject matter context https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193337/compute-a-certain-separability-probability-via-a-constrained-4d-integration-ov. In that context, we have to add together
the two results of Student multiplying them by $6/\pi^2$ and add them to a companion third term (continued in next comment)

Comment: we had already been able to calculate ourselves—that is, the integral of 
$\frac{3 u^2 \sqrt{-a^2 u^2-b^2+1}}{\pi }$—giving us $\frac{2 \left(\sqrt{(1-u^2) u^2}+\sin ^{-1}\left(u\right)\right)}{\pi }$.
This sum of the three terms proves—rather surprisingly—to be precisely equal to the “two-rebit Lovas-Andai separability function”
(eq. (2) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01973).

Comment: Thanks, student. What would be of major importance to the underlying "separability probability question" would be the integration over $u \in [0,1]$ of the product of each of your two functions with $\frac{12 u^2 \left(u^6+9 u^4-9 u^2-12 \left(u^4+u^2\right) \log
   (u)-1\right)}{\left(u^2-1\right)^5}$. The result of the first integration times $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ appears (via numeric means) to equal $-\frac{41 C}{2}-69-\pi  (-22+\pi -37 \log (2)+15 \log (3))$, where  Catalan's constant is indicated. Similarly, the result of the second integration times $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ appears

Comment: (again via numeric means) to equal $\frac{1}{6} (-191 C-395+\pi  (139-15 \pi +125 \log (2)+\log (27))) \approx 0.20672$. (I was steered to these two conjectures by wolframalpha.com.) The result of the second integration minus the result of the first integration plus $\frac{919}{5}-264 \log (2)$ should equal the sought "rebit-retrit separability probability" of $-\frac{34 C}{3}+\frac{5609}{30}-264 \log (2)+\frac{1}{6} \pi  (7-9 \pi -97 \log (2)+93
   \log (3)) \approx 0.747925$. My attempts to use Mathematica to perform these computations has so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater Could you check the numerical factors in front of your integrals? First I get $2u$ times your value for the third integral (see edited answer), and secondly it seems surprising that all three are of the same form but two have factors of $8/3$ whereas one has a factor of $8/\pi$.

Comment: OK, thanks. One immediate comment is that in tranforming the original variable $U$ to $u^2$--which, at the time I thought would facilitate analyses--the factor of $2 u$ was picked up--but, in retrospect I should have placed it in the other factor  comprising the integrands. We should get, I think,  $\frac{6}{\pi^2} \cdot $ (your second formula minus your first) added to the third later term, agreeing with the "Lovas-Andai" formula (eq. (2)) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01973 (with $u \equiv \varepsilon$). I'll try to be more expansive/clearer later this A.M. after commute.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater I have also added the remaining integral over $u$ to the answer.

Comment: Great, student! I'll have to peruse. In the meantime--trying to extend my previous "rebit-retrit" analysis to the "qubit-qutrit" case--I've come up with the integrand $\frac{\left(a^2+b^2-1\right) \sin ^{-1}\left(a b \sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(a^2-1\right)
   \left(b^2-1\right)}}\right)}{a b}$ (same limits as before). I've so far made a half-hearted attempt to follow your scheme (polar coordinates,...), but seemed to get something unwieldy after the transformation to $x,y$. This later problem pertains, at this point, to a new sub-optimal solution, so maybe there will be subsequent problems too.

Comment: @student--OMG--it took me a little while to absorb that--in your bonus round--you found an amazing answer to the rebit-retrit separability probability. So, does this equal my Catalan-number-based conjecture? I'll check on this now. If you can pull off this bonus round, I strongly suspect that you can also find an exact solution for the two-rebit problem--that has so far evaded an exact expression.

Comment: So, my Catalan number conjecture is not correct--only matching your formula to eight places. Also, I tried addressing that two-rebit (monotone metric) separability probability question, you might also be able to address, in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189538/sum-a-certain-hypergeometric-function-based-expression-pertaining-to-an-integrat--but that's probably not a good way to present it to you-and I think I should more directly state the problem. It's discussed on p. 44 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.01973.pdf, but maybe it's best if I state it as a new independent question.

Comment: The related two-rebit problem--that perhaps will not be so simple, on second thought, involves replacing $B$ in your "bonus round" with $\frac{8 \left(8 \left(u^4+u^2\right) E\left(1-\frac{1}{u^2}\right)-\left(u^2+3\right)
   \left(3 u^2+1\right) K\left(1-\frac{1}{u^2}\right)\right)}{\pi  \sqrt{u}
   \left(u^2-1\right)^3}$, where the elliptic functions are indicated. This is precisely the problem considered on p. 16 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01410.pdf. In their notation your $A$ is their $\tilde{\chi}_1(\varepsilon)$

Comment: The numerical answer they give is 0.26223. I was trying--unsuccessfully--to get an underlying exact answer in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189538/sum-a-certain-hypergeometric-function-based-expression-pertaining-to-an-integrat--but

Comment: @PaulB.Slater The "qubit-qutrit" integrand, integrated over the unit disk for $a, b$, gives $\pi - \pi^3/6$. I will have a think about the more difficult integrand. But I am not sure that the comments are the right place to discuss -- the chat, or perhaps email, might be more appropriate?

Comment: student: you can certainly email me--slater@kitp.ucsb.edu. I'm often on the go--here-and-there, so chatting could be difficult--though it seemed fine/fun yesterday.

Comment: Can you perform the "Bonus round" calculation with $B=\frac{990 u^7 \left((u-1) (u+1) \left(5 u^{12}+789 u^{10}+6669 u^8+12794 u^6+6669
   u^4+789 u^2+5\right)-420 u^2 \left(u^2+1\right) \left(u^8+14 u^6+36 u^4+14
   u^2+1\right) \log (u)\right)}{\left(u^2-1\right)^{13}}$? This would yield the separability probability if the "Lovas-Andai two-rebit function" $\tilde{\chi}_1(\varepsilon)=A$ could be applied in the unrestricted 20-dimensional $6 \times 6$ rebit-retrit density matrix scenario. It, however, clearly can't, since the calculation I requested should be about 0.509, rather than 0.131.

Comment: I take it that the "Bonus round" calculation with $B$, the indicated elliptic function expression, was not similarly amenable to an exact calculation.

Comment: In the penultimate comment, instead of 0.509, 0.62532581 seems more proper. While I have a comment box open, how about also $B=\frac{15360 u^4 \left(u^8+28 u^6-28 u^2-24 \left(u^6+3 u^4+u^2\right) \log
   (u)-1\right)}{\left(225 \pi ^2-2048\right) \left(u^2-1\right)^7}$. Should give about 0.76383602445068, maybe exactly 11/15 (sqrt(145) - 11)≈0.7638360244476833